# Update a column when value is not null JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, spring, jooq

I want to update a column only when the given value is not null in the POJO I am receiving.

I want to implement this SQL:

```
Update TABLE table_name SET column_name = COALESCE(value, column_name)
```

Here is the function I have written in JOOQ

```
     public int updateCompany(final Company company) {

        return dslContext.update(COMPANY)
                .set(COMPANY.REGISTERED_NAME, company.getRegisteredName())
                .set(COMPANY.TRADING_NAME, coalesce(COMPANY.TRADING_NAME, company.getTradingName()))
                .set(COMPANY.ADDRESS_ID, coalesce(COMPANY.ADDRESS_ID, company.getAddressId()))
                .where(COMPANY.ID.eq(company.getId()))
                .execute();
    }
```

Comment: Keep transaction size down, avoid transaction conflicts: `Update TABLE table_name SET column_name = value WHERE value IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the bug that [Simon Martinelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66742934/521799) found, the problem here is that there's no overload `DSL.coalesce(T, Field<T>...)`, which your code is assuming there is. Not unreasonably so, there's usually such an overload. In this case, there isn't for historic reasons. In Java 6, there was no `@SafeVarargs` yet, and jOOQ 3.14 still supports Java 6. With jOOQ 3.15 no longer supporting Java 6, this could be fixed. I've created an issue for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11690

In the meantime, you have to explicitly wrap your bind value using [`DSL.val()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val(T)), see [the manual section about bind values](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/).

E.g.

```java
.set(COMPANY.TRADING_NAME, coalesce(val(company.getTradingName()), COMPANY.TRADING_NAME)
.set(COMPANY.ADDRESS_ID, coalesce(val(company.getAddressId()), COMPANY.ADDRESS_ID))
```

Alternatively, use the equivalent [2-argument `DSL.nvl(T, Field<T>)` function](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#nvl(T,org.jooq.Field)), which doesn't have this limitation as it doesn't have a varargs parameter.

Answer (score 2):

In the update statement you do

```
coalesce(<input_value>, column_name)
```

But in the jOOQ query you do

```
coalesce(column_name, <input_value>)
```

So you should change the order

```
 public int updateCompany(final Company company) {

    return dslContext.update(COMPANY)
            .set(COMPANY.REGISTERED_NAME, company.getRegisteredName())
            .set(COMPANY.TRADING_NAME, coalesce(company.getTradingName(), COMPANY.TRADING_NAME))
            .set(COMPANY.ADDRESS_ID, coalesce(company.getAddressId(), COMPANY.ADDRESS_ID))
            .where(COMPANY.ID.eq(company.getId()))
            .execute();
}
```